# В админке Wordpress не видно постов

Tags: wordpress

При нажатии на posts, pages и другие вкладки по умолчанию, ничего не отображается. Плагины уже пробовал деактивировать - ничего не меняется.

[image]
<sub>(источник: [joxi.ru](http://joxi.ru/KAxZ77F4KVMnm8.jpg))</sub>

Как починить такое?

Comment: что в консоле браузера пишет? может есть ошибки там какие то?

Comment: попробуйте сменить тему на дефолтную, в которую не вносились никакие изменения